# Displaying output with multiple values

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

```
Get-EC2Instance |%{ $_.RunningInstance } | 
    select-object InstanceId,LaunchTime,@{Name='Value'; Expression={$_.Tag.Value} }, @{Name='Key'; Expression={$_.Tag.Key} }
```

[image]

Each Value and Key have multiple values as you can see in the screenshot. How to rewrite the code so the output can look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution; it's not the most elegant, but hopefully solves your problem:

**For Your Use Case**

```
Get-EC2Instance | `
    %{ 
        $x = $.RunningInstance;
        $x.Tag | select-object 
             @{Name="InstanceId"; Expression={$x.InstanceId}}
            ,@{Name="LaunchTime"; Expression={$x.LaunchTime}}
            ,@{Name="Value";      Expression={$_.Value}}
            ,@{Name="Key";        Expression={$_.Key}};
    }
```

**Simple Demo**

```
cls
$x = @(
     (New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{Name='one';List=@('a','b','c');})
    ,(New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{Name='two';List=@('d','e','f');})
    ,(New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{Name='three';List=@('g','h','i');})
    ,(New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{Name='four';List=@('j','k','l');})
    ,(New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{Name='five';List=@('m','n','o');})
)

#show what the preparation code produced:
#$x | select Name, List

#show the output we're after
$x | %{$n=$_.Name; $_.List | select @{Name="Name";Expression={$n}},@{Name="ListValue";Expression={$_}}}
```

Comment: Hi That doesnt solve my problem. $x.Tag  doesnt contain the instance and launchtime values.

Comment: @minisch then make a simple change for your debugging. This answer has a correct logical approach to your problem.

Comment: @minisch: the code doesn't take `InstanceId` or `LaunchTime` from `$x.Tag`, but from `$x` directly.  Take a closer look and you'll see value and key come from `$_` which represents `$x.Tag` whilst `InstanceId` and `LaunchTime` come from `$x`.

Comment: $output  | %{$n=$_.InstanceId; $_.Key | select @{Name="InstanceID";Expression={$n}},@{Name="Key";Expression={$_}}} I tried this command it worked exactly the way I wanted but when I add additional "Value" column doesnt work: $output  | %{$n=$_.InstanceId; $_.Key; $_.Value | select @{Name="InstanceID";Expression={$n}},@{Name="Key";Expression={$_}},@{Name="Value";Expression={$_}}}     Any idea why it doesnt work?

Comment: You have `$_.Key; $_.Value | select @{Name`... where you should have `$_.Tag | select @{Name`...

Comment: ps. I've created a cmdlet which may help (i.e. you can just call the cmdlet rather than having to tweak the more complex code above: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94509/powershell-unpivot-object - not yet perfect, but being on code review its imperfections will soon be highlighted / can be resolved (or a better alternative found).