# Powershell Split items in a string

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I cant figure out how this works...please help...

```psh
$output = Get-EC2Instance |%{ $_.RunningInstance } | select-object InstanceId,@{Name='Key'; Expression={$_.Tag.Key} },@{Name='Value'; Expression={$_.Tag.Value} }
```

This command displays :
[image]

I run the second command below which splits "Key" (Each instanceId has multiple Keys associated to it. Each key has its associated value):

```psh
$output  | %{$n=$_.InstanceId; $_.Key | select @{Name="InstanceID";Expression={$n}},@{Name="Key";Expression={$_}}}
```

The output is 
[image]

How to modify the second command to include "`Value`" column (each key has a associated value)?

Comment: Are `Key` and `Value` parallel lists (same numerical index in both is a matched pair)?

Comment: correct Etan. they are parallel lists. Each key has one value.

Comment: How is this different from your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015310/displayign-output-with-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

I "think" you want this:

```
$output | Foreach {$vals=$_.Value; $n=$_.InstanceId; $i = 0; $_.Key |  
                   Select @{Name="InstanceID";Expression={$n}},
                          @{Name="Key";Expression={$_}},
                          @{Name="Value";Expression={$vals[$i++]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure to follow but if I understand :

```
$a =$output[0]
$a["one_key"] -> "One_Value"
```

Then

```
$output  | %{$n=$_; $_.Key | select @{Name="InstanceID";Expression={$($n.InstanceId)}},@{Name="Key";Expression={$_}},@{Name="Value";Expression={$n[$_]}}}
```

I can't test it ans it's very early in the morning so be lenient.